# Change coords of area tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, area, coords

I'm trying to change the coords of an area tag using JavaScript. Here is my HTML code:

```
<a onclick="changeCoords('area-1', '50,825,220,1225');">Button</a>                      
<img id="page-1" class="shadow margin-20 width-900" src="pics/pages/razei-harefua-1.jpg"     usemap="#research-map">
<map name="research-map">
    <area id="area-1" shape="rect" coords="110,980,390,1150" href="some URL">
</map>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function changeCoords(areaID, newCoords) {
    var x = document.getElementById(areaID).coords;
    x = newCoords;
}
```

Comment: A good question should generally provide more info on what you would like to achieve. And some context, as it might affect what a complete answer has to include...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to just change the coords property with the newCoords, then simply write:

```
document.getElementById(areaID).coords = newCoords
```

Your example doesn't work because you are assigning the value of coords to the x variable, and then you just change the value of x to the newCoords value. The x variable isn't a reference to the coords property, is just an allocated memory space that in your case stores the value of coords, and then that value is overwritten with the value of newCoords.

Comment: No, but this ( http://jsfiddle.net/6348jamj/8/ ) works. The DIV element doesn't have the coords property, that's why your example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setAttribute`:

```
function changeCoords(areaID, newCoords) {
    var x = document.getElementById(areaID);
    x.setAttribute('coords', newCoords);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6348jamj/5/)